# Calculate 3 month future of Oil

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

This question is from an exercise sheet for financial mathematics.

> Calculate the $3$-month future on Oil given the following information:
>
> - Spot Oil is trading at $90$ USD per barrel.
> - USD interest rates are at $2$%.
> - Storage charges for Oil are $1$ USD per barrel per month.
> - Insurance against Oil disasters costs $0.20$c per barrel.
> - A spike in demand is likely to push Oil prices up by $5$ USD per barrel.

Last point seems to be a trick but I am not sure if I can include it somehow using a random variable that is 1 or 0 depending on whether there is a spike or not.

The formula I have for a forward is

$Fwd = S + (\text{gains from holding currency}) - (\text{losses from not holding asset})$

$S$ is the value of the underlying asset.  I think I have to do something with this to adapt is to the question but I am not quite sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arbitrage-free pricing model tells us that the economic value of buying one barrel of oil now and selling one barrel's worth of 3-month futures must be the same as placing the price of the barrel of oil on deposit for 3 months.

If we buy one barrel at spot this costs $90$ USD. Over 3 months we have to pay $3$ USD storage costs and $0.20$ USD insurance. If the 3-moth futures price is $F$ USD per barrel then the value of the barrel in 3 months time is $F - 3.2$ USD.

If we place $90$ USD on deposit for 3 months at $2$% interest per annum, in 3 months time this is worth $90 + \frac{1.8}{4} = 90.45$ USD. So we have

$F - 3.2 = 90.45$

The "likely" rise in oil prices is irrelevant in arbitrage-free pricing.

Comment: $90+\frac{1.8}{4}$ does not $= 94.5$USD

Comment: @ʎpoqou Good spot ! I have corrected to $90.45$.